# How do i set properties from command line args in Camel Spring standalone app

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a Camel Spring standalone application:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception{
    Main main = new Main();
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camel-context.xml");
    main.setApplicationContext(context);
    main.run();
}
```

I have some properties which need to be used when configuring routes. These properties will come from command line args when starting the application. The route is defined:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        Map<String, String> loadedValues = getValuesFromProperties( envrionment );

        // route definition
    }
}
```

How do i get these properties to use in the configure method? I don't know what the properties names or values are before running the application. I'm going to have thousands of possible properties.

I have tried the to get them with CommandLinePropertySource, but the values are set after the config() method is called:

```
    CommandLinePropertySource clps = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camel-context.xml");
    context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(clps);
    main.setApplicationContext(context);
```

I have also tried creating a context, adding the properties and then creating the context with my camel-context.xml file, but this didn't work either.

What are my options to load properties from command line args into my application?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a refresh after you added the property source?

```
context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(clps);
context.refresh();
```